# Sending Notifications to user while app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background, notifications

I've done lots of research on this from Firebase to App delegate but I don't understand a lot. I'm trying to send notifications to the user when someone else has posted something in my app - like on Instagram or social media post notifications. Can someone please point me in the right direction for how to do this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: How about taking a look at this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/  Otherwise post what you have been trying

Comment: @MauricioChirino   Ok so I have the code for a local notification that DOES work, and this code to activate it:           Database.database().reference().child("\(mySchool!)/posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.notifyNewPost()
            
        })                                                                                                                   So when there's a new post (.childAdded) I do the notification. Do i put this in app-delegate?

Comment: I agree with @UpholderOfTruth, you gotta share more code than that in order to get in context with you.

Comment: If you are trying to notify the user that a new post has been added by someone else running their version of the app then that notification needs to also be generated outside of your app.  You app then just responds to that notification however it was generated.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I looked at the tutorial, and it looks very helpful, but I don't want to send the notification manually myself, but programatically. I already have my custom notification working, and the code to trigger it, I just need to know where to put it...

Comment: How does you app know that someone else has posted something?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth With the Firebase Realtime Database. The '.childAdded' is how I know when there is a new post.

Comment: Is what you want that if User A is using the app and User B is using the app then when User B posts User A should receive a notification?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yeah that's what I'm trying

Comment: One instance of your app can't send notifications to another.  Local notifications allow your app to inform your user of something when it's not running in the foreground only.  What you are looking at using is remote notifications and that requires some kind of server to generate the notifications and in this case you are talking about using Firebase.  Basically when your app posts this is obviously going to be stored remotely so that all apps have access and the process of this generates the remote notification not your app directly.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth But if I know there is a new post by checking the database (for the sake of the discussion, let's say that I know there is a new post), couldn't I send a notification for that? My point is the '.childAdded' function executes when there's a new post, so wouldn't I be able to just put my local notification code in there? If I do go with the Firebase, after I set everything up with the notifications, if someone posts something, will Firebase then push out a notification to the user? Sorry if this is obvious, I'm really new the notiication thing! Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: No problem.  When you say checking the database do you mean the local copy on the device itself?  Surely somewhere you have a central database of posts.  Wherever that is is what should be sending the notifications so that even when you app is not running the device still gets one.  Or do you mean when your app is running it checks and sends a local notification which is unusual but you can do it.  I'm not sure if Firebase has automatic sending of notifications as I don't use it but I will take a look

Comment: Thanks, and I mean the Firebase Database, on the internet. So I check it ( .childAdded) in the background and then send a local notification.

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

If you have setup your iOS app for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), when the user first opens your app, the apps talks to the google servers and generated a token specific to that device.

### What is a token?

The token is like a device identifier. You use that token to tell firebase which exact device you want it to send the notification to. (The token changes on uninstalling and reinstalling the app and may even on a restore).

### On the backend

Now, you have to configure your app to send that token to your backend and store it as one of the tokens for the user currently logged in. (This should happen every time they login from that device, and you should remove that token from the server when the user logs out).

Whenever you need to send out a notification, you'll have to make a POST request to the FCM server. This POST request will contain the device token and the content of the notification, along with other authorization info. Detailed instructions are provided at
[Send a Notification Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#send_a_notification_message)

Comment: Can I send the notification programmatically? Or is the only way to do this manually in the console?

Comment: If you are using firebase to manage your database, then you might wanna look into Firebase cloud functions. You can trigger functions to send notifications. You can refer to the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?authuser=0

And this article might help you as well: https://www.skcript.com/svr/using-firebase-cloud-functions/

Comment: If you want to send the notifications based on the activities of a user (eg, when I send you a text) you can configure your app such that when I send out a text, ill ask firebase to send a notification as well.

For that refer to the last paragraph of my answer